# C share macro which is a method of accessing a member of a struct between multiple files

Tags: c, struct, macros

So I want to share a macro between different .c files which "returns" the "content" (which is a member of a struct) of a element of a matrix of structures. I have these files:

matrix.h:

```
#ifndef _MATRIX_H
#define _MATRIX_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matrix_Pos_Struct Matrix_Pos;

#define GET_CONTENT(i, j) (mz[(i)][(j)].content)

#endif
```

matrix.c:

```
#include "matrix.h"

extern Matrix_Pos** mz;

struct Matrix_Pos_Struct{
    char content;
    char visited;
};
```

And then I have another_file.c that invokes the macro GET_CONTENT(), and mz is a double pointer that is declared in yet another file where the main() is at. How can I make this while achieving the most abstraction possible? This is fora university project and the teacher values abstraction

Comment: First things first, ditch the macro and write an actual function instead.

Comment: But I wanted to make a macro, can I have the same effect by declaring a static inline function?

Comment: Yes, but it needs only be one of `static` or `inline`.

Comment: @Quentin if my function is static, will there be a performance gain? Because I'm having a hard time defining it as a inline function because I have to define the function in matrix.h and as the structure is not define yet (it is only defined in matrix.c) it gives a error saying "undefined reference to `mz'". If I define mz in matrix.h it says that mz doesn't have a field named content, because the structure is only defined later in the matrix.c

Comment: If only `matrix.c` knows about the definition of `Matrix_Pos_Struct`, there is no point in defining the macro in `matrix.h`, since no one could use it without knowing the struct. An inline function definition in the header fails on the spot for this very reason. From then on, it's straightforward to just define the function inside `matrix.c` and you won't notice any performance difference since any compiler will inline it. Note that the function has the added bonus that you can *declare* it in the header for other source files to call it without knowing the struct: this goes towards your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that making a function is a better way of doing this, instead of a macro